# Beautiful soup output {{ model.attribute }} instead normal text

Tags: python, django-models, beautifulsoup, python-requests, urllib

My machine :

- List item
- Ubuntu 16.04.
- Python 3.5.2.
- bs4 4.6.0.
- lxml 3.8.0.

I'm trying to parse [tokopedia site](https://www.tokopedia.com/search?st=product&q=baju%20baru). This is my code:

```
tokopedia_link = 'https://www.tokopedia.com/search?st=product&q=baju+baru'
req = urllib.request.Request(tokopedia_link)
req.add_header('User-agent', 'Mozilla 5.10')
with urllib.request.urlopen(req) as response:
    the_page = response.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(the_page, "lxml")
print (soup.prettify())
```

The output i think is django model framework ex. {{ model.attribute }}.

[image]

But if i save the tokopedia site then place it in apache2 site folder and then i change tokopedia_link to my local site, it output normally.

Any suggestion?

**Update 1:**
I check the output of `print(the_page)` and it print the same strange result. So my conclusion is the problem is when opening the url.

**Update 2:**
I try using requests module to create connection to the url. Still same result.

```
payload = {'st': 'product', 'q': 'baju baru'}
headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
r = requests.post('http://www.tokopedia.com/search', params=payload, headers=headers)
```

**Update 3:**
I try parsing amazon.com and the output is normal. Did web based on django framework cause this issue?. I'll create django based web for research.
**Update 4:**
I created the django based web then parse it and nothing strange with the output.
**Update 5:**
I do more research and it might be issue with angularjs. I see `ng-cloak ng-binding` in the site code.

Comment: You should post your _problem solved_ update as an answer for clarity to future users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update 6:
Problem solved. The angularjs based web is the issue. Urllib or requests module cant solve the connection so i use selenium and it works.